# horizontal table and chart in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

[image: table and chart]

Hi,
I want to create horizontal table and chart in plotly( kind of subplot). I am not able to create it. Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant by this:[image]

Created by using code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2,
    shared_xaxes=True,
    horizontal_spacing=0.03,
    specs=[[{"type": "table"}, {"type": "bar"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=['Country', 'Year', 'Population'],
            font=dict(size=12),
            align="left"
    ),
    cells=dict(
        values=[
           ['United States', 2000, 282200000],
           ['Canada', 2000, 27790000],
           ['United States', 2005, 295500000],
        ],
        align = "left")
    ),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
   go.Bar(
       x=[1, 2, 3],
       y=[4, 5, 6],
   ), 
   row=1, col=2
) 

fig.update_layout(
    height=500,
    showlegend=False,
    title_text="example plot",
)

fig.show()
```

I have used [plotly express table](https://plotly.com/python/table/) instead of factory.

used sample data and layout, you can change as per your desire.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, it worked for me, thank you. The only thing is: my result set is a dataframe(extracted from a SQL query). Is it possible to get the dictionary values from my dataframe  rather than hard coding the values for x and y axis?

Comment: Yes, you can specify x and y values directly as  df['col1'] and df['col2']. No need to hard code values. It was just example.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much.